# Parallax effect only on a specific parts of a webpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, parallax

I'm trying to implement a parallax effect to a website. But I have a question: can this be done inside a specific part of the page? Or, to force some parts of the website to be static while others are parallax?

I have a header and footer and their position is defined in the CSS with "position:fixed;". So, I'd like to have the parallax effect between them. I think that this can cause some problems because of the images positions and so on.

I made a research and all the parallax website based that I found the effect is global to all page.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to implement a parallax effect to a website. But I have a question: can this be done inside a specific part of the page? Or, to force some parts of the website to be static while others are parallax?

Yes you can do it.

---

There are some problems if your page has not fixed width - you need to bind on window resize recalculations of `offset()` and `height` of your parallax div

Also you must set `<img/>`'s `width` and `height`.

For more performance bind event calls only if `$(document).scrollTop()` is in related range.